# converting promiseAll to gradual promises resolve(every 3promises for example) does not work

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, ecmascript-2016

I have a list of promises and currently I am using promiseAll to resolve them

Here is my code for now:

```
   const pageFutures = myQuery.pages.map(async (pageNumber: number) => {
      const urlObject: any = await this._service.getResultURL(searchRecord.details.id, authorization, pageNumber);
      if (!urlObject.url) {
        // throw error
      }
      const data = await rp.get({
        gzip: true,
        headers: {
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        },
        json: true,
        uri: `${urlObject.url}`,
      })

      const objects = data.objects.filter((object: any) => object.type === "observed-data" && object.created);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._resultsDatastore.bulkInsert(
          databaseName,
          objects
        ).then(succ => {
          resolve(succ)
        }, err => {
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    })
    const all: any = await Promise.all(pageFutures).catch(e => {
       console.log(e)
     })
```

So as you see here I use promise all and it works:

```
const all: any = await Promise.all(pageFutures).catch(e => {
   console.log(e)
 })
```

However I noticed it affects the database performance wise so I decided to resolve every 3 of them at a time.
for that I was thinking of different ways like cwait, async pool or wrting my own iterator
but I get confused on how to do that?

For example when I use cwait:

```
let promiseQueue = new TaskQueue(Promise,3);
const all=new Promise.map(pageFutures, promiseQueue.wrap(()=>{}));
```

I do not know what to pass inside the wrap so I pass ()=>{} for now plus I get

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'PromiseConstructor'.
```

So whatever way I can get it working(my own iterator or any library) I am ok with as far as I have a good understanding of it.
I appreciate if anyone can shed light on that and help me to get out of this confusion?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.Promise does not have Map method.. I think you store all values in pageFutures array.. So pageFutures.Map would be correct...

Comment: @kumaran I was trying to follwo cwait library instruction but it is so confusing. All I need is to execute promises in pageFutures step by step. so 3 promises in pageFutures should be resolved first then the next 3 ...

Comment: @kumaran if I follow what you said with cwait I get this: const all=new pageFutures.map( promiseQueue.wrap(()=>{})); which is not a valid option

Comment: What is the actual question here?   I can't seem to really tell.  Can you please clarify what exactly you want help with?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some remarks:

- Indeed, in your current setup, the database may have to process several bulk inserts concurrently. But that concurrency is not *caused* by using `Promise.all`. Even if you had left out `Promise.all` from your code, it would still have that behaviour. That is because the promises were already created, and so the database requests will be executed any way.
- Not related to your issue, but don't use the [promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it): there is no need to create a promise with `new Promise` when you already have a promise in your hands: `bulkInsert()` returns a promise, so return that one.

As your concern is about the database load, I would limit the work initiated by the `pageFutures` promises to the non-database aspects: they don't have to wait for eachother's resolution, so that code can stay like it was.

Let those promises resolve with what you currently store in `objects`: the data you want to have inserted. Then concatenate all those arrays together to one big array, and feed that to *one* database `bulkInsert()` call.

Here is how that could look:

```
const pageFutures = myQuery.pages.map(async (pageNumber: number) => {
  const urlObject: any = await this._service.getResultURL(searchRecord.details.id, 
                                                         authorization, pageNumber);
  if (!urlObject.url) { // throw error }
  const data = await rp.get({
    gzip: true,
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate" },
    json: true,
    uri: `${urlObject.url}`,
  });
  // Return here, don't access the database yet...
  return data.objects.filter((object: any) => object.type === "observed-data" 
                                           && object.created);
});
const all: any = await Promise.all(pageFutures).catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
  return []; // in case of error, still return an array
}).flat(); // flatten it, so all data chunks are concatenated in one long array
// Don't create a new Promise with `new`, only to wrap an other promise. 
//   It is an antipattern. Use the promise returned by `bulkInsert`
return this._resultsDatastore.bulkInsert(databaseName, objects);
```

This uses `.flat()` which is rather new. In case you have no support for it, look at the alternatives provided on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score 1):

First, you asked a question about a failing solution attempt. That is called [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

So in fact, as I understand your question, you want to delay some DB request.

You don't want to delay the *resolving* of a `Promise` created by a DB request... *Like No! Don't try that!* The promise wil resolve when the DB will return a result. It's a bad idea to interfere with that process.

I banged my head a while with the library you tried... But I could not do anything to solve your issue with it. So I came with the idea of just looping the data and setting some timeouts.

I made a runnable demo here: [Delaying DB request in small batch](https://repl.it/@Bes7weB/Delaying-DB-request-in-small-batch)

Here is the code. Notice that I simulated some data and a DB request. You will have to adapt it. You also will have to adjust the timeout delay. A full second certainly is too long.

```
// That part is to simulate some data you would like to save.

// Let's make it a random amount for fun.
let howMuch = Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)

// A fake data array...
let someData = []
for(let i=0; i<howMuch; i++){
  someData.push("Data #"+i)
}

console.log("Some feak data")
console.log(someData)
console.log("")

// So we have some data that look real. (lol)
// We want to save it by small group

// And that is to simulate your DB request.
let saveToDB = (data, dataIterator) => {
  console.log("Requesting DB...")
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("Request #"+dataIterator+" complete.");
  })
}

// Ok, we have everything. Let's proceed!
let batchSize = 3 // The amount of request to do at once.
let delay = 1000  // The delay between each batch.

// Loop through all the data you have.
for(let i=0;i<someData.length;i++){

  if(i%batchSize == 0){
    console.log("Splitting in batch...")

    // Process a batch on one timeout.
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => {

      // An empty line to clarify the console.
      console.log("")

      // Grouping the request by the "batchSize" or less if we're almost done.
      for(let j=0;j<batchSize;j++){

        // If there still is data to process.
        if(i+j < someData.length){

          // Your real database request goes here.
          saveToDB(someData[i+j], i+j).then(result=>{
            console.log(result)
            // Do something with the result.
            // ...
          })

        } // END if there is still data.

      } // END sending requests for that batch.

    },delay*i)  // Timeout delay.

  } // END splitting in batch.

} // END for each data.
```